# Solve the initial value problem $xy'=y(xy-1), y(e^{-1})=e$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solve the initial value problem 
$xy'=y(xy-1), y(e^{-1})=e$

I was given the hint to use the substitution, but don't know how to find the proper substitution. What's the general rule of thumb in finding a substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xy'=y(xy-1), y(e^{-1})=e$$
$$xy'+y=xy^2$$
Since $(xy)'=y'x+y$
$$(xy)'=\frac {(xy)^2}x$$
Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Do you then let u=xy do the job? I think I get it.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Then integrate and substitute back u. Note that this equation is a Bernouili's differential equation @Beacon

Comment: For Bernouilli's equation $y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^n$ the substitution $u=y^{1-n}$ will transform the DE into a first order linear equation thats easy to solve.